# Popen fails when intput has an ampersand?

Tags: python, escaping, subprocess, popen

I have a python script that returns info about a song that is currently playing:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["/home/lucas/media/.deadbeeffiles/deadbeef", "--nowplaying", "%t"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
track = out.decode("utf-8")

p = subprocess.Popen(["/home/lucas/media/.deadbeeffiles/deadbeef", "--nowplaying", "%a"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
artist = out.decode("utf-8")

p = subprocess.Popen(["/home/lucas/media/.deadbeeffiles/deadbeef", "--nowplaying", "%b"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
album = out.decode("utf-8")

outString = "\"%s\" by %s on %s" % (track, artist, album)

q = subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Now Playing", outString])
```

However, if `track` (or presumably `artist` or `album`) has an `&` in it, the `notify-send` notification only has `Now playing` without any of the text in `outString`. I tried adding this under `track = out.decode("utf-8")`:

```
track = track.replace("&", "\&")
```

But it does nothing. However,

```
track = track.replace("&", "and")
```

Works fine. What could be causing it to fail? `subprocess.Popen` is supposed to take care of special characters (such as the space in "Now Playing"), and I know that adding an escape to `&` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Hi. It would have helped if you had provided a self-contained (see http://SSCCE.ORG) test, like this one: http://ideone.com/FRTVWU. Regardless, I can't reproduce your error on Ubuntu 13.04. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Robᵩ I'm using Crunchbang (Debian Wheezy). I ran your code and it still caused the error, so it's got to be an issue with `notify-send`

Comment: Perhaps. Try running `notify-send 'Now Playing' 'Turkey & Dressing'` from a shell command line. If that fails, then `notify-send` is certainly the culprit.

Comment: Just for grins, try `track.replace("&", "&amp;")`.

Comment: Yep, it was notify-send. Talk about quality, it doesn't _actually_ change anything when you add quotes?

Comment: have you tried `notify-send 'Now Playing' 'Turkey \& Dressing'` in bash i.e., double escape the ampersand in Python: `r"\&" == "\\&"`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian still didn't work

Comment: @LucasPhillips: `notify-send 'Now Playing' 'Turkey & Dressing'` works as is on Ubuntu 12.04 (`libnotify-bin-0.7.5-1`)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I have the same version of libnotify, but I'm on Debian. Weird.